# Python: Why can't I call a method outside the if loop

Tags: python, methods, do-while

I am a beginner and am having trouble understanding why I can call this method inside the if loop, but outside I get an error.

The code below is from a main.py file. It imports a character class from another file and a room class from a third. When I was trouble shooting, I discovered that everything worked fine as below. But when the two commented out lines were uncommented, there was an error from the second uncommented line, print(inhabitant.describe()),  which said: <AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
no attribute 'describe'>

All works fine now and I will delete the two commented lines below, but my question is why does the identical line of code work inside the if loopbut not immediately outside it.

The self.get_details() method works fine
The self.get_character() method works fine
Why does print(inhabitant.describe()) work inside the if loop but not outside it.
Please ignore the #print("\n ")

Any help would be appreciated.

```
while True:
    print("\n")
    current_room.get_details()

    inhabitant = current_room.get_character()
   #print(inhabitant)
   #print(inhabitant.describe())

    if inhabitant is not None:
        #print("\n")
        print(inhabitant.describe())
```

Below is the code from the character.py file. The inhabitant spoken about in the code above is a subclass, Enemy.

```
 class Character():

    # Create a character
    def __init__(self, char_name, char_description, M_or_F):
        self.name = char_name
        self.description = char_description
        self.gender = M_or_F
        self.pronoun = None
        self.poss_pronoun = None
        self.conversation = None

    # Set up pronouns
    def set_pronoun(self):
        if self.gender == "m":
            self.pronoun = "He"
        else:
            self.pronoun = "She"
        return self.pronoun

    # Set up possessive pronouns
    def set_poss_pronoun(self):
        if self.gender == "m":
            self.pronoun = "His"
        else:
            self.pronoun = "Her"
        return self.pronoun

    # Describe this character
    def describe(self):
        return("\n%s is here!\n%s" %(self.name, self.description))

    # Set what this character will say when talked to
    def set_conversation(self, conversation):
        self.conversation = conversation

    # Talk to this character
    def talk(self):
        if self.conversation is not None:
            print("[" + self.name + " says]: " + self.conversation)
        else:
            print(self.name + " doesn't want to talk to you")

    # Fight with this character
    def fight(self, combat_item):
        print(self.name + " doesn't want to fight with you")
        return True

class Enemy(Character):
    def __init__(self, char_name, char_description, M_or_F):
        super().__init__(char_name, char_description, M_or_F)
        self.weakness = None
        self.possession = None

    def set_weakness(self, weak_point):
        self.weakness = weak_point

    def get_weakness(self):
        return self.weakness

    def set_possession(self, possession):
        self.possession = possession

    def get_possession(self):
        return self.possession

    def fight(self, combat_item):
        if combat_item == self.weakness:
            print("\nYou fend %s off with the %s" %(self.name, combat_item))
            return True
        else:
            print("\n%s crushes you, puny adventurer" %(self.name))
            return False

    def bribe(self, bribe_item):
        print("\nOK, I'll take your %s.\nHere is the %s you wanted." %(bribe_item, self.posession))
        self.possession = bribe_item 

    #def sleep(self, )
```

Comment: Please show us whats `current_room`.

Comment: In the `current_room.get_character()` method, I think you need to have a return statement, such that it is not a `None Type`

Comment: @U12-Forward The current_room is a Dining Hall. There is no problem with that code. I did make a mistake and ask why it not printing outside the WHILE loop, when i meant the IF loop. All things take place inside the while loop. I've edited my post.

Comment: @Japs6901 Please edit in your `current_room` class into the question

Comment: @Japs6901 We need to see the `current_room` class... please show it to us

Comment: @Japs6901 That's the only way we could help

Comment: Uncomment the failing lines, run the code and post the traceback. That will show us where the error is. Perhaps `describe` is calling another method `describe` on some other object, we don't know.

Comment: Does the `print(inhabitant.describe())` inside of the `if` run and print something?

Comment: I looks like you assigned inhabitant to a function get_character() that might not be returning anything.   Not sure if you are trying to instantiate a class current room which as the function describe() but without the code we have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tdelaney The traceback:
    print(inhabitant.describe())      
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has 
no attribute 'describe'

Comment: @tdelaney Does the print(inhabitant.describe()) inside of the if run and print something?
Yes it does. But the one outside does not

Comment: @Japs6901 The problem isn't in the code you provided, it's in the class

Comment: @Japs6901 It's fine

Comment: @U12-Forward just added class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. An AttributeError was thrown because the game began in the kitchen where there was no Character assigned, therefore it could not fulfill print(inhabitant.describe()). Inside the IF statement, it first checked to see if the room contained a character before trying to describe it.

Thanks for all your help.